# Finding a function greater or less than factorial function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

suppose we are given the sequence: $a_n = (-1)^n\frac{1}{n!}$ using squeeze theorem find the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^n\frac{1}{n!}$$

using the squeeze theorem.

For factorials, $a_n$ how do you find $b_n, c_n$ such that

$b_n \le a_n \le c_n$

Comment: You could use $b_n=-1/n$, $c_n=1/n$.

Comment: Do you have a counterexample (with $n\ge1$)?

Comment: Nevermind. I looked at it the other way around. +1, I just misread, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$\frac{-1}{n!} \leq \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \leq \frac{1}{n!}$$

Comment: How is this true?

Comment: Well, Amad, you could multiply through by $n$-factorial.